# How to auto generate a multidimensional array given two variables in php

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I am trying to generate a multidimensional array through a function that receives two variables ($a and $b) and should return a multidimensional array where $a and $b determine the width and the height of the multidimensional array.
I am doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is.
Thanks in advance for the answe

```
<?php
$map = array();
print_r($map);
function mapGenerator($a, $b) {
    $hex = '<div class="hex"><div class="top"></div><div class="middle"></div><div class="bottom"></div></div>';
    $hexEven = '<div class="row even">';
    $hexOdd = '<div class="row">';
    $rowEnd = '</div><!-- END ROW -->';
    for ($row = 0; $row < $b; ++$row) {
        if ($row % 2 == 0) {    
            $map[$row][0] = "$hexEven";
        } else {
            $map[$row][0] = "$hexOdd";
        }
        for ($cell = 0; $cell <= $a; ++$cell) {
            $map[$row][$cell] = "$hex";
        }
        ++$cell;
        $map[$row][$cell] = "$rowEnd";
    }
    return $map;
}
mapGenerator(4,7);
echo "<br>";
print_r($map);
?>
```

The final result should be something like this:

```
$map = array(
    array("$hexOdd","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$rowEnd"),
    array("$hexEven","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$rowEnd"),
    array("$hexOdd","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$rowEnd"),
    array("$hexEven","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$rowEnd"),
    array("$hexOdd","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$rowEnd"),
    array("$hexEven","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$rowEnd"),
    array("$hexOdd","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$rowEnd"),
    array("$hexEven","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$hex","$rowEnd"),
    );
```

Comment: What is your current and expected output? (Don't forgot to assign your return value ;D `$map = mapGenerator(4,7);` A few seconds and vampires will come)

Comment: Thanks Rizier123, that code is part of a bigger document in which I have a form with a radio button that determines the size of the map and sends the global variable $_POST to a page with a switch case break control that determines the variable. I have tried to modify the code, but even if I add the statement $map = mapGenerator(5,7); it generates an array with no values, even though it generates the empty arrays inside.

Comment: I think your main problem is that you don't view your source code!

Comment: I have tried the code in the real page, where the html tags generated in the array should show an hexagonal map, but they didn't appear anyway :(

Comment: What do you mean with *hexagonal map* ? (My code output's exactly what you watn: http://ideone.com/AFb1q4)

Answer (score 1):

You have a few errors in your code:

(Side Note: Since you assign html tags to your array elements, right click -> view source code to see your array)

```
$map = array();
print_r($map);

function mapGenerator($a, $b) {
    $hex = '<div class="hex"><div class="top"></div><div class="middle"></div><div class="bottom"></div></div>';
    $hexEven = '<div class="row even">';
    $hexOdd = '<div class="row">';
    $rowEnd = '</div><!-- END ROW -->';

    for ($row = 0; $row < $a*2; ++$row) {
                        //^^^^ Use $a and multiple it with 2 if you want 8 innerArrays with your current function call
        if ($row % 2 == 0) {    
            $map[$row][0] = "$hexOdd";
                           //^^^^^^^ Switched the variables
        } else {
            $map[$row][0] = "$hexEven";
        }

        for ($cell = 1; $cell <= $b*2-1; ++$cell) {
                   //^           ^^^^^^ Use $b and multiple it with 2 minus 1 if you want 13 array elements with your current function call
                   //| Begin with 1 since 0 already has a value
            $map[$row][$cell] = "$hex";
        }
        //removed unnecessary increment of $cell 
        $map[$row][$cell] = "$rowEnd";
    }

    return $map;
}
$map = mapGenerator(4,7);
//^ Don't forget to assign the function call
echo "<br>";
print_r($map);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function mapGenerator($a, $b) {
    global $map; /* add this or just define $map=array(); inside the function (better) */
    $hex = '<div class="hex"><div class="top"></div><div class="middle"></div><div class="bottom"></div></div>';
    $hexEven = '<div class="row even">';
    $hexOdd = '<div class="row">';
    $rowEnd = '</div><!-- END ROW -->';
    for ($row = 0; $row < $b; $row++) { /* Inverted ++$row with $row++ */
        $map[$row] = array(); /* Add this line */
        if ($row % 2 == 0) {    
            $map[$row][0] = "$hexEven";
        } else {
            $map[$row][0] = "$hexOdd";
        }
        for ($cell = 0; $cell <= $a; $cell++) { /* Inverted ++$cell with $cell++ */
            $map[$row][$cell] = "$hex";
        }
        $cell++;
        $map[$row][$cell] = "$rowEnd";
    }
    return $map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You just use two for loops, one creating the "row" and the other creating the "columns" inside the "row". Something like this would do it:

```
$array  = array();
$size   = 10;
$filler = "VALUE";

for ($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++) {
    // Create "rows"
    $array[$i] = array();
    for ($j = 0; $j < $size; $j++) {
        // Add "columns" to the "rows"
        $array[$i][$j] = $filler;
    }
}
```